# Appium - Automation testing using java script

Tags: javascript, appium

I am new to appium and I am facing some Issues in Appium testing. Please let me know if you would able to solve these issues:

1. When i run my code, after some time it is Displaying the screen as “Open app again”. Upon debug - It is unable to find the element. Appium is able to find it sometimes but fails sometimes.

Comment: Adding your code that has the problem will help us solve your problem faster. Show us what you've tried. And whats not working.

Comment: Please find the code below:

Comment: Edit your question to add code there.

Comment: public class PartnerLogin extends base {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
         driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView [@text = 'Camera']").click();
  
 driver.findElementById("com.android.camera2:id/done_button").click();         
         
         
         driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button [@text = 'PROCEED']").click();
         
         
   
         Thread.sleep(4000);
         //ADD TRUCK
     
           driver.findElementById("com.tripin.truckpartner:id/ll_map_add");